# How to ContinueWith antecedent's state object?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

Is there a way to pass a state object to the ContinueWith function in .net 4.0?  This option is available in .net 4.5.

I reviewed the source code of .net 4.0, it hard codes the state object to null when it creates the continued Task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET 4 version of `ContinueWith` does not provide this option.

You can, however, use a closure or wrap the data into the `Task<T>` itself, depending on how this is generated, in order to get access to state data created within the antecedent task.

Answer (score 1):

The AsyncState member of the task should be the value of the the state you provided the original task, even when referenced as an antecedent task in ContinueWith.  This is valid  for .Net 4.0.

```
Task.Factory
    .StartNew( state => ..., myState)
    .ContinueWith( task => task.AsyncState == myState);
```